# Java Manifest Trusted-library and ResourceBundle.getBundle()

Tags: java, manifest

I am trying to get rid of the "block applet" warning message while loading external resources from a signed applet (mixing code).

If I leave the applet like it is right now, it displays the warning message, and clicking "no block" makes the applet work properly.
On the other hand, If I just modify the applet to add the "Trusted-library: true" attribute to the manifest file in order to accept non-signed external resources, it makes the applet crash.

Debugging the applet, I've found that it crashes while running the following line:

```
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("conf/basic","en_EN");
```

The exception thrown is:

```
java.util.MissingResourceException: 
Can't find bundle for base name conf/basic, locale en_EN
```

I have checked that conf folder with file basic_en_EN.properties is present at the same level that the applet jar (otherwhise it would not work even without trusted-library)

Reading [Java 7 doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/mixed_code.html) it says that adding trusted-library should fix the mixing signed/unsigned code problem, but it doesn't.

Furthermore, in Java 7 doc it doesn't say anything about ResourceBundle.getBundle() method issues, but it does in [Java 6 doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/mixed_code.html):

> Code in a jar file that is to be marked with the Trusted-Library
>   manifest attribute may need to be modified slightly if it uses calls
>   that are class loader dependent, such as the single parameter version
>   of Class.forName(), Class.getResource(), and
>   Class.getResourceAsStream(), some variants of
>   java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(), and any other methods which
>   operate relative to their immediate caller's defining loader. Changes
>   only need to be made if the requested class or resource might be found
>   in a jar file which is not a Trusted-Library (and is therefore loaded
>   by the normal Web Start or applet class loader).

Even I'm working with Java 7, I've found [this post](https://community.oracle.com/message/5205081) where they explain a method to replace getBundle() in Java 6. I've tried it without any result.

My Manifest file is:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: Company
Main-Class: src.applet.MyApplet
Class-Path: ./
Application-name: myApplet
Permissions: all-permissions
Trusted-Library: true
Caller-Allowable-Codebase: *
Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase: *
```

I have compiled and tested it with both jdk and jre 7u45/7u51, having the same result.

Any help or advice will be apreciated.